# Zend mysql fetchAll and count

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have following SQL query:

```
SELECT `ka`.`id`, COUNT(kk.id) AS `clicks` FROM `karriere_anzeige` AS `ka` LEFT JOIN `karriere_klicks` AS `kk` ON `ka`.`id` = `kk`.`id_anzeige` WHERE (ka.id_kunde = '616') GROUP BY `ka`.`id`
```

If I run this query in phpMyAdmin I get proper results, f.e.:

id   | clicks

4803 | 75

4822 | 144

However this attempt:

```
$rowset = $db->fetchAll($select);
```

Returns this rowset:

```
array(2) {
    [0] => array(2) {
        ["id"] => string(4) "4803"
        ["clicks"] => string(1) "0"
    }
    [1] => array(2) {
        ["id"] => string(4) "4822"
        ["clicks"] => string(1) "0"
    }
}
```

$db is Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql object

When I do INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN, running the SQL query in phpMyAdmin returns few rows. Doing the same with Zend Framework, as described above, returns zero rows. I suppose I do generally something wrong, but I can't figure out what is it. Can somebody give me a hint?

Comment: post your $select (Zend_Db_Select) query object

Comment: sorry guys - I was obviously working too much last week - everything works fine and the result of the SQL query which is run directly in database and through Zend are the same - I was connecting my application with wrong database - anyway thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to pass the string as SQL try somethng like:

```
//This assumes access from a controller/action
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$sql = "SELECT `ka`.`id`, COUNT(kk.id) AS `clicks` FROM `karriere_anzeige` AS `ka` LEFT JOIN `karriere_klicks` AS `kk` ON `ka`.`id` = `kk`.`id_anzeige` WHERE (ka.id_kunde = '616') GROUP BY `ka`.`id`";
$stmt = new Zend_Db_Statement_PDO($db, $sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

you can also build a [Zend_Db_Select](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html) object to query your table with.